# Cannot bind a negative Integer to an Entry Text

Tags: xaml, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an Entry on a Xamarin Forms ContentPage that I have bound to a ViewModel property QtyIn which is an Int32:

```
private int _qtyIn;
public int QtyIn
{
    get { return _qtyIn; }
    set
    {
        if (_qtyIn != value)
        {
            _qtyIn = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("QtyIn");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Path=Source.QtyIn, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource intToStringConverter}}" />
```

And my IValueConverter:

```
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // from Int32 to String
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    // String to Int
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int parsedInt = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out parsedInt))
        {
            return parsedInt;
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try and enter a negative number, starting with the '-' minus sign, the binding fails because it can't convert '-' to an Int32. This is the error I see in the mono output when running this app on an Android device:

```
05-03 15:19:27.923 I/mono-stdout(19384): Binding: - can not be converted to type 'System.Int32'
```

Does anyone know how to bind an integer to an  Text property that allows negative numbers? I can't find any documentation about this on Xamarin's website or forums.

In WPF, I would use the UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus property to only do the conversion after the whole number is entered, but Xamarin Forms doesn't have this property available.

Comment: So your requirement is: If the `Text` is invalid (not convertibe to int), `QtyIn` should be set to 0, or?

Comment: My requirement is if I'm trying to enter the number -123, that it should allow me to enter it into the Entry. When I type a -, it is not a valid integer so the text changes to 0. The property should only change when the Entry  loses focus, however Xamarin Forms doesn't have the UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus property.

Comment: On wich platform do you test? In my testcase (android, binding **without** converter) it just produces the warning and only updates the property if it can be converted.

Comment: I am testing on Android (API 19). I removed my IValueConverter and I see this whenever I press the '-' key on the onscreen keyboard:  05-04 10:12:42.683 I/mono-stdout(21775): Binding: - can not be converted to type 'System.Int32'

Comment: Yes, that's just the warning. If you type further, the property gets updated properly.

Comment: No, the '-' never appears in the Entry text, if I type '-', 1, 2, 3. I just see a positive 123 number.

Comment: Thats strage. I tested it on Android M and it's working as described. Do you have the latest Xamarin.Forms package?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111020/discussion-between-mangist-and-sven-michael-stube).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning a 0 if the value passed is "-"?

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)

{
    int parsedInt = 0;

    if (value == "-") return 0;

    if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out parsedInt))
    {
        return parsedInt;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Yes but that just changes the Entry text to 0, and deletes the - that I just typed on the keyboard.

Comment: I would file a bug and see what they say: bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: I posted on their forums and am waiting for someone to respond. I don't think it's necessarily a bug (as I understand what it's doing), I just need a way around it, preferably need them to implement UpdateSourceTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you return `value`, which is a string with <kbd>-</kbd> and try to pass it to an `Int32` (back in your ViewModel).

Instead put second state into your logic. Return a null if parsing did fail - this also helps avoiding problems with any other character input.

```cs
public class IntToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // from Int32 to String
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.ToString() ?? "";
    }

    // String to Int
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int parsedInt = 0;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out parsedInt))
        {
            return parsedInt;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And here is the ViewModel:

```cs
private int? _qtyIn;
public int? QtyInNullable // you should bind on this one in your entry
{
    get { return _qtyIn; }
    set
    {
        if (_qtyIn != value)
        {
            _qtyIn = value;
            if (value != null)
                OnPropertyChanged("QtyInNullable");
            OnPropertyChanged("QtyIn");
        }
    }
}

public int QtyIn // you should bind on this one in your entry
{
    get { return _qtyIn ?? 0; }
}
```

And bind it:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Path=Source.QtyInNullable, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource intToStringConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I understand the problem, Xamarin Forms doesn't have the UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus property which would solve this. Returning a zero just overwrites the Entry '-' that I typed with a '0'. There is no way to enter e.g. -123. Whenever I type a - it changes to a 0.

Comment: Ah I see. In this case, you should do some more work to check this different state - I changed my answer.

Comment: Do you know whether changing the ViewModel property to a nullable int? actually fixes this issue? If so that would be really simple and helpful.

Comment: Well, I changed it one more time introducing a second property just for this case. Then you don't have side effects

Comment: This doesn't work, Binding: - can not be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'

Comment: I changed and tested it now, and now it's working on my device. Sorry I should not code without test so late ;)